# Error: Variable length differs in lm regression using paste function

Tags: r, linear-regression, paste

I have generated randomly a dataset that has been split in two (L and I).

First I run the regression on L using all the covariates.
After defining the set of variables that are significantly different form zero I want to run the regression on I using this set of variables.

```
reg_L = lm(y ~ ., data = data)
S_hat = as.data.frame(round(summary(reg_L)$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"], 3)<0.05)
S_hat_L = rownames(which(S_hat==TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE))
```

Therefore here I want to run the new model that doesn't work only due to a problem in the specification of the variable x.
What am I doing wrong?

```
# Using the I proportion to construct the p-values
x = noquote(paste(S_hat_L, collapse = " + "))
reg_I = lm(y ~ x, data = data)
summary(reg_I)
```

Comment: Your data have probably missings which are being deleted during regression. Since you're attempting to use all variables you could try `reg_L = lm(y ~ ., data=data[complete.cases(data), ])`.

Comment: No my data don't have missing because I have generated them. Moreover, I am not using all the variables...

Comment: `y  ~  .`: you're attempting to predict `y` with all other variables.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way than trying to manipulate a formula programmatically would be to remove the unwanted predictors from the data:

```
wanted <- summary(fit)$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"] < 0.05
reduced.data <- data[, wanted]
reg_S <- lm(y ~ ., data=reduced.data)
```

Note however, that it is more robust with respect to out-of-sample performance to reduce variables with the LASSO. This will yield a model that has some coefficients set to zero, but the other coefficients are adjusted in such a way that the uot-of-sample performance will be better.